# Sharepoint 2013 SelectedRefinementControlsJson throwing error

Tags: json, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

I am trying to update the sharepoint 2013 refiner webpart thru the below powershell script:

```
$spweb = Get-SPWeb "http://da-server/search/"
$page = $spweb.GetFile("Pages/results.aspx")
$page.CheckOut()
# Find the Refinement web part
$webPartManager = $spweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("http://da-  server/search/Pages/results.aspx", [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$rwp = $webpartmanager.webparts | ? { $_.title -eq 'Refinement' }
# Refiners are updated by changing the JSON
 $j = $rwp.SelectedRefinementControlsJson | ConvertFrom-Json
 $j.refinerConfigurations | % { if ($_.propertyName -eq 'LastModifiedTime') {     $_.displayName = 'Mod Time'; }
**$rwp.SelectedRefinementControlsJson = ConvertTo-Json $j -Compress** This line throwing the error.
 # Save our changes
 $webpartmanager.SaveChanges($rwp)          # save changes to webpart
 $page.CheckIn('Changed last mod refiner')
 $page.Publish('Changed last mod refiner')
```

The above highlighted line 10 throwing the below error:

```
Exception setting "SelectedRefinementControlsJson": No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'Micrososft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.RefinementControl[]'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ConvertTo-Json $j -Depth 3`

Out of box, `Modified By` property has more than one aliases and it's a nested level. By default `ConvertTo-Json` only goes 2 level. So you have to use `-depth` to convert it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have in one or more refiners only one alias defined. In this case the PS ConvertTo-Json function converts the array to a string. More details found here https://superuser.com/questions/414650/why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string

As I struggled with the same issue here is my solution

```
Function ConvertTo-Json {

param($inputObject)

    if ($inputObject -eq $null) { "null" }
    else {
        switch ($inputObject.GetType().Name) {
            "String" { '"' + $inputObject +'"' }
            "Boolean" { 
                if($inputObject){
                    "true"
                }
                else {
                    "false"
                }
            }
            "Object[]" {
                $items = @()
                $inputObject | % {
                    $items += ConvertTo-Json $_
                }
                $ofs = ","; "[" + [string]$items + "]"
            }
            "PSCustomObject" {
                $properties = @()
                $inputObject | Get-Member -MemberType *Property | % {
                    $properties += '"'+ $($_.Name) + '":' + $(ConvertTo-Json $inputObject.($_.Name))
                }
                $ofs = ","; "{" + [string]$properties + "}"
            }
            default { $inputObject }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it can be used as before, but without -Compress parameter

```
$rwp.SelectedRefinementControlsJson = ConvertTo-Json $j
```